# download file from google cloud compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I use format like

```
gcloud compute copy-files user@instance-1:/home/user/file \ /home/user/Desktop \ --zone europe-west1-b
```

it gives me error

> no such file or directory as desktop

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me - Mac OS X

```
gcloud compute scp username@vminstance:source-directory local-directory --zone instancezone
```

Before you have to set PATH correctly for using Google SDK.

```
PATH=/your-google-cloud-sdk-folder/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 25):

If you're connecting to the instance via https://console.cloud.google.com using `SSH for Google Cloud Platform`, you can download a specific file via "Download file" from the Settings menu (accessible through the settings icon in upper right corner).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I use `ls $PWD/file.txt` to get the full path and paste it to the input text.

Comment: works for small files, but painly slow for bigger ones

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file on gcloud compute engine instance which you want to transfer to local machine or another instance, the best way is to upload the file to google cloud storage. Make the link public and download it.
Follow these docs https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects

Suppose you have a file `example.zip` that you want to download.
First create a bucket in gcloud storage, suppose `example10`.

You have multiple language options to upload a file. I'll be showing examples in Curl and Python.

> To use Restful API on curl you first have to get a OAUTH2_TOKEN to access the
>   cloud storage.

Then type this on Terminal

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @example.zip \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/zip" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/example10/o?uploadType=media&name=myexample.zip"
```

> Now I'll be showing you an example using Python

Make sure that your instance has **Full Access to all Cloud APIs** if you don't want to use an OAUTH2_TOKEN. Then you can use python to upload the object.

Install python's google cloud storage client

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

Then open the python command line by entering `python` on terminal

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))

upload_blob("example10", "example.zip", "myexample.zip")
```

You can find option to give Full Access to all Cloud APIs by clicking on instances's name and editing the details.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

Syntax :

```
gcloud compute scp <UserName>@<ServerName/InstanceName>:~/<FilePathFromInstance> <LocalSystemFilePath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way for Windows users is using remote application such as **MobaXterm**. After SSH to your unix servers, you can easily download/upload files from/to servers via GUI.

Answer (score -2):

Landed up using google storage buckets to move large files between compute engine and workstations. Moved multiple GBs in a few seconds instead of hours trying to download individual files.